# Issue in launching Chrome via Selenium VBA

Tags: vba, google-chrome, selenium

I have tried to launch Chrome browser via Selenium VBA by using the below code. I am getting this error when executing the code "WebRequestError
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive." But IE browser is working fine.

```
Sub samp()
Dim drv As New Selenium.WebDriver
drv.Start "Chrome"
drv.Get "www.google.com"
End Sub
```

Comment: what happens when you try combining them to 1 line, try `drv.Start "Chrome", "www.google.com"` . (you do have Chorme installed, right ?`

Comment: I got the same error message.

Comment: Same code works in Chrome 53 version but not working in 55 version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this by installing the latest ChromeDriver, and replacing the .exe-file with the file located in my AppData.

**Requirements**

- Download and install SeleniumBasic VBA, and set the reference in VBA editor (https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/)

**Steps**

1. Download latest WebDriver from: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
2. Open folder C:\Users\ `Username`\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic
3. Replace chromedriver.exe with existing file

**Example**

Now this example code below works as intended

```
Sub driver()
    Dim selenium As New selenium.WebDriver

    selenium.Start "chrome", "http://google.com"
    selenium.Get "/"

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand why people write Get request like this,
while it should be this (not saying above one is wrong)

selenium.Start "chrome"
selenium.Get "http://google.com"